Office update 2405 causes slowness in access in loading forms
We experience issues with the May 30 release of Office 365, from version 2405 17628.20110
We experience issues with Microsoft Access. The issue that we experience is that loading and closing of forms takes longer and longer when you are using the application. Basiccally what we see is that the drawing of the form takes longer each time a form is opened.
We have written a function to illustrate this:
Public Function speedtest_rke(Optional M As Integer = 300)
'this is a speedtest that opens and closes forms. the drawing makes it become slow
Dim start As Single
Dim formOpen As Single
Dim T As Long
    Debug.Print "try id", "open form", "close form", "total time"
    For T = 1 To M
        start = Timer
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Tabel1", acNormal
        formOpen = Timer
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "Tabel1"
        Debug.Print T, formOpen - start, Timer - formOpen, Timer - start
    Next T
End Function

When we execute the function, this are the results:
try id        open form     close form    total time
 1             0,4140625     0,0546875     0,46875 
 2             0,265625      0,0625        0,328125 
 3             0,2421875     0,078125      0,3203125 
 4             0,2578125     0,0546875     0,3125 
 5             0,2578125     0,0546875     0,3125 
 6             0,2578125     0,0625        0,3203125 
 7             0,28125       0,0703125     0,3515625 
 8             0,2578125     0,0625        0,3203125 
 9             0,2734375     0,0625        0,3359375 
 10            0,2421875     0,046875      0,2890625 
 11            0,265625      0,0625        0,328125 
 12            0,265625      0,078125      0,34375 
 13            0,2890625     0,0546875     0,34375 
 14            0,265625      0,0546875     0,3203125 
 15            0,25          0,0703125     0,3203125 
 16            0,390625      0,046875      0,4375 
 17            0,2734375     0,0703125     0,34375 
 18            0,296875      0,0546875     0,3515625 
 19            0,25          0,0546875     0,3046875 
 20            0,265625      0,0546875     0,3203125 
 21            0,2734375     0,0859375     0,359375 
 22            0,265625      0,0703125     0,3359375 
 23            0,2578125     0,0546875     0,3125 
 24            0,2734375     0,0625        0,3359375 
 25            0,3046875     0,0859375     0,390625 
 26            0,2734375     0,0625        0,3359375 
 27            0,3046875     0,0546875     0,359375 
 28            0,2578125     0,078125      0,3359375 
 29            0,2890625     0,0703125     0,359375 
 30            0,2890625     0,078125      0,3671875 
 31            0,3125        0,0859375     0,3984375 
 32            0,2890625     0,09375       0,3828125 
 33            0,3125        0,0859375     0,3984375 
 34            0,2890625     0,0859375     0,375 
 35            0,34375       0,0859375     0,4296875 
 36            0,296875      0,09375       0,390625 
 37            0,3515625     0,078125      0,4296875 
 38            0,3046875     0,078125      0,3828125 
 39            0,296875      0,1015625     0,3984375 
 40            0,3359375     0,09375       0,4296875 
 41            0,3125        0,1171875     0,4296875 
 42            0,34375       0,1015625     0,4453125 
 43            0,3046875     0,1015625     0,40625 
 44            0,4140625     0,1015625     0,515625 
 45            0,3515625     0,109375      0,4609375 
 46            0,3203125     0,1328125     0,453125 
 47            0,34375       0,109375      0,453125 
 48            0,3671875     0,1015625     0,46875 
 49            0,3515625     0,1328125     0,484375 
 50            0,3203125     0,125         0,4453125 
 51            0,375         0,109375      0,484375 
 52            0,34375       0,109375      0,453125 
 53            0,375         0,1171875     0,4921875 
 54            0,328125      0,1328125     0,4609375 
 55            0,359375      0,15625       0,515625 
 56            0,3671875     0,1484375     0,515625 
 57            0,390625      0,15625       0,546875 
 58            0,3671875     0,1640625     0,53125 
 59            0,3671875     0,15625       0,5234375 
 60            0,359375      0,1640625     0,5234375 
 61            0,359375      0,125         0,484375 
 62            0,375         0,1171875     0,4921875 
 63            0,3828125     0,125         0,5078125 
 64            0,390625      0,140625      0,53125 
 65            0,390625      0,1171875     0,5078125 
 66            0,359375      0,15625       0,515625 
 67            0,3671875     0,1328125     0,5 
 68            0,34375       0,1640625     0,5078125 
 69            0,3515625     0,140625      0,4921875 
 70            0,3671875     0,1640625     0,53125 
 71            0,3671875     0,15625       0,5234375 
 72            0,375         0,171875      0,546875 
 73            0,3671875     0,171875      0,5390625 
 74            0,390625      0,1640625     0,5546875 
 75            0,3828125     0,1640625     0,546875 
 76            0,40625       0,1640625     0,5703125 
 77            0,375         0,1796875     0,5546875 
 78            0,4375        0,15625       0,59375 
 79            0,3828125     0,1796875     0,5625 
 80            0,4453125     0,1875        0,6328125 
 81            0,390625      0,1640625     0,5546875 
 82            0,390625      0,1796875     0,5703125 
 83            0,4453125     0,171875      0,6171875 
 84            0,4296875     0,2421875     0,671875 
 85            0,40625       0,1796875     0,5859375 
 86            0,4453125     0,21875       0,6640625 
 87            0,46875       0,203125      0,671875 
 88            0,4453125     0,21875       0,6640625 
 89            0,4765625     0,2109375     0,6875 
 90            0,515625      0,234375      0,75 
 91            0,515625      0,21875       0,734375 
 92            0,5234375     0,2265625     0,75 
 93            0,4375        0,21875       0,65625 
 94            0,4453125     0,2265625     0,671875 
 95            0,4453125     0,2265625     0,671875 
 96            0,453125      0,21875       0,671875 
 97            0,4609375     0,2421875     0,703125 
 98            0,5           0,2265625     0,7265625 
 99            0,53125       0,2578125     0,7890625 
 100           0,546875      0,3125        0,859375 
 101           0,6015625     0,3046875     0,90625 
 102           0,4921875     0,3046875     0,796875 
 103           0,4921875     0,25          0,7421875 
 104           0,578125      0,234375      0,8125 
 105           0,5546875     0,2734375     0,828125 
 106           0,5546875     0,25          0,8046875 
 107           0,515625      0,296875      0,8125 
 108           0,5703125     0,3046875     0,875 
 109           0,5546875     0,3203125     0,875 
 110           0,609375      0,2890625     0,8984375 
 111           0,59375       0,296875      0,890625 
 112           0,6171875     0,296875      0,9140625 
 113           0,609375      0,296875      0,90625 
 114           0,6015625     0,28125       0,8828125 
 115           0,5625        0,3359375     0,8984375 
 116           0,59375       0,34375       0,9375 
 117           0,578125      0,34375       0,921875 
 118           0,6328125     0,3203125     0,953125 
 119           0,59375       0,3125        0,90625 
 120           0,578125      0,34375       0,921875 
 121           0,6640625     0,2890625     0,953125 
 122           0,6171875     0,3359375     0,953125 
 123           0,6328125     0,3125        0,9453125 
 124           0,6015625     0,328125      0,9296875 
 125           0,6171875     0,3203125     0,9375 
 126           0,6171875     0,3125        0,9296875 
 127           0,6875        0,3671875     1,054688 
 128           0,7109375     0,4140625     1,125 
 129           0,671875      0,359375      1,03125 
 130           0,6796875     0,3828125     1,0625 
 131           0,6953125     0,3828125     1,078125 
 132           0,7421875     0,4453125     1,1875 
 133           0,71875       0,4140625     1,132813 
 134           0,7734375     0,3828125     1,15625 
 135           0,71875       0,4296875     1,148438 
 136           0,734375      0,46875       1,203125 
 137           0,734375      0,421875      1,15625 
 138           0,703125      0,4296875     1,132813 
 139           0,7734375     0,4609375     1,234375 
 140           0,7890625     0,46875       1,257813 
 141           0,7421875     0,5078125     1,25 
 142           0,890625      0,5546875     1,445313 
 143           1,375         0,5234375     1,898438 
 144           0,9453125     0,5546875     1,5 
 145           0,9921875     0,578125      1,570313 
 146           0,9296875     0,53125       1,460938 
 147           0,9453125     0,59375       1,539063 
 148           1,390625      0,828125      2,21875 
 149           1,375         0,9140625     2,289063 
 150           1,390625      0,8671875     2,257813 
 151           1,390625      0,765625      2,15625 
 152           1,539063      0,8125        2,351563 
 153           1,28125       0,71875       2 
 154           1,3125        0,734375      2,046875 
 155           1,179688      0,6171875     1,796875 
 156           1,117188      0,7421875     1,859375 
 157           1,375         0,8671875     2,242188 
 158           1,3125        0,8359375     2,148438 
 159           1,070313      0,6875        1,757813 
 160           1,070313      0,7109375     1,78125 
 161           0,8359375     0,59375       1,429688 
 162           0,8828125     0,53125       1,414063 
 163           0,828125      0,578125      1,40625 
 164           0,859375      0,5625        1,421875 
 165           0,9140625     0,546875      1,460938 
 166           0,875         0,5390625     1,414063 
 167           0,8671875     0,5625        1,429688 
 168           0,875         0,609375      1,484375 
 169           0,9140625     0,6015625     1,515625 
 170           0,9140625     0,59375       1,507813 
 171           0,9453125     0,6328125     1,578125 
 172           1,03125       0,59375       1,625 
 173           0,9375        0,640625      1,578125 
 174           0,9140625     0,65625       1,570313 
 175           0,9453125     0,640625      1,585938 
 176           1,023438      0,953125      1,976563 
 177           0,90625       0,5546875     1,460938 
 178           0,9765625     0,546875      1,523438 
 179           0,90625       0,609375      1,515625 
 180           0,9609375     0,703125      1,664063 
 181           1,054688      0,765625      1,820313 
 182           1,5           1,046875      2,546875 
 183           1,40625       0,9296875     2,335938 
 184           1,601563      1,585938      3,1875 
 185           2,382813      2,84375       5,226563 
 186           2,492188      0,984375      3,476563 
 187           1,164063      0,796875      1,960938 
 188           2,039063      1,039063      3,078125 
 189           1,421875      0,8828125     2,304688 
 190           1,320313      0,9765625     2,296875 
 191           1,296875      0,9140625     2,210938 
 192           1,382813      0,8984375     2,28125 
 193           1,414063      0,921875      2,335938 
 194           1,335938      0,8515625     2,1875 
 195           1,257813      0,859375      2,117188 
 196           1,382813      0,890625      2,273438 
 197           1,25          1,148438      2,398438 
 198           2,046875      0,9375        2,984375 
 199           1,539063      1,1875        2,726563 
 200           1,5           1,109375      2,609375 
 201           1,585938      0,96875       2,554688 
 202           1,414063      0,9609375     2,375 
 203           1,5625        1,140625      2,703125 
 204           1,679688      1,15625       2,835938 
 205           1,742188      1,351563      3,09375 
 206           2,03125       1,265625      3,296875 
 207           1,921875      1,195313      3,117188 
 208           1,820313      1,148438      2,96875 
 209           1,726563      1,390625      3,117188 
 210           1,773438      1,109375      2,882813 
 211           1,445313      1,03125       2,476563 
 212           1,546875      1,132813      2,679688 
 213           1,710938      1,125         2,835938 
 214           1,609375      1,085938      2,695313 
 215           1,507813      1,179688      2,6875 
 216           1,570313      1,085938      2,65625 
 217           1,695313      1,273438      2,96875 
 218           1,640625      1,140625      2,78125 
 219           1,453125      1,070313      2,523438 
 220           1,515625      1,203125      2,71875 
 221           1,609375      1,1875        2,796875 
 222           1,71875       1,234375      2,953125 
 223           2,039063      1,273438      3,3125 
 224           1,71875       1,3125        3,03125 
 225           1,757813      1,25          3,007813 
 226           1,648438      1,15625       2,804688 
 227           1,632813      1,171875      2,804688 
 228           1,765625      1,226563      2,992188 
 229           1,617188      1,1875        2,804688 
 230           1,695313      1,25          2,945313 
 231           2,140625      1,351563      3,492188 
 232           1,890625      1,320313      3,210938 
 233           1,71875       1,25          2,96875 
 234           1,867188      1,25          3,117188 
 235           1,914063      1,40625       3,320313 
 236           2,007813      1,320313      3,328125 
 237           1,804688      1,28125       3,085938 
 238           1,789063      1,359375      3,148438 
 239           2,085938      1,375         3,460938 
 240           1,554688      1,3125        2,867188 
 241           2,0625        1,546875      3,609375 
 242           2,007813      1,414063      3,421875 
 243           1,859375      1,375         3,234375 
 244           2             1,625         3,625 
 245           2,203125      1,695313      3,898438 
 246           2,414063      2,46875       4,882813 
 247           2,804688      1,796875      4,601563 
 248           2,71875       1,609375      4,328125 
 249           1,835938      1             2,835938 
 250           1,609375      1,085938      2,695313 
 251           1,585938      1,945313      3,53125 
 252           1,929688      1,25          3,179688 
 253           1,53125       1,148438      2,679688 
 254           1,515625      1,21875       2,734375 
 255           2,328125      2,015625      4,34375 
 256           2,460938      1,789063      4,25 
 257           2,140625      1,757813      3,898438 
 258           2,171875      1,789063      3,960938 
 259           2,117188      1,367188      3,484375 
 260           2,257813      1,5625        3,820313 
 261           2,265625      1,726563      3,992188 
 262           2,507813      1,8125        4,320313 
 263           2,710938      1,96875       4,679688 
 264           2,734375      2,09375       4,828125 
 265           2,765625      2,03125       4,796875 
 266           2,453125      1,96875       4,421875 
 267           2,71875       2,523438      5,242188 
 268           2,5           1,921875      4,421875 
 269           2,546875      2,015625      4,5625 
 270           2,5           1,75          4,25 
 271           2,460938      1,859375      4,320313 
 272           2,742188      1,992188      4,734375 
 273           2,414063      2,039063      4,453125 
 274           2,734375      2,015625      4,75 
 275           2,546875      2,171875      4,71875 
 276           3,210938      2,414063      5,625 
 277           3,1875        2,46875       5,65625 
 278           3,015625      2,046875      5,0625 
 279           2,125         1,773438      3,898438 
 280           2,414063      1,757813      4,171875 
 281           2,382813      1,78125       4,164063 
 282           2,296875      1,976563      4,273438 
 283           2,859375      1,773438      4,632813 
 284           2,429688      1,867188      4,296875 
 285           2,375         1,78125       4,15625 
 286           2,335938      1,78125       4,117188 
 287           2,5           2             4,5 
 288           2,3125        1,859375      4,171875 
 289           2,453125      1,828125      4,28125 
 290           2,390625      1,914063      4,304688 
 291           2,671875      2,046875      4,71875 
 292           2,515625      1,96875       4,484375 
 293           2,757813      2,164063      4,921875 
 294           2,023438      1,546875      3,570313 
 295           3,140625      2,703125      5,84375 
 296           3,882813      2,773438      6,65625 
 297           3,15625       4,34375       7,5 
 298           8,429688      4,539063      12,96875 
 299           7,429688      4,554688      11,98438 
 300           4,867188      3,179688      8,046875 

In above overview you can see that when we start the access application the loading of the form takes approx. 0,3s, and the closing of the form takes 0,05s
After 100 opens the timings are 0,5 and 0,3s
After 200 opens the timings are 1,4s and 1s
After almost 300 opens the timings are 2+s and 1,8s
When we execute this same recursive function in an older version of Microsoft access the timings are stable.
We have tested this with several forms. And we see this with all forms. The only difference is the loading speed – which depends on the number of objects that are drawn on the form. The more objects the slower and the higher the increase in becoming slower.
Anyone knows if this bug is already reported / fixed by Microsoft?
I have created a new ms access database, with this recursive function.
and I see that it becomes slow depending on the number of objects on the form.
I have also tested the recursive function with database access (dcount) but then I don't see any slowness. So it must be in the drawing of the form

Post any code as text, not low resolution images that are impossible to read. And don't seem to be recursive either.

After almost 300 opens the timings are 2+s and 1,8s sounds like the loop is flooding memory with objects. Closing a form in VBA/VB6 doesn't remove the object from memory

I have added it in text, that is better readable.

The must be a leak somewhere, I guess it is an issue with garbage collection.
The thing is that is exesists since update 2405. If I revert the version back to 2404 the timings are stable.

"Nice" find, good to know. 2405 is quite new, is this the "bleeding edge, get all fresh bugs" channel? -- Note that a loop is not recursive . It's just a loop.

VBA doesn't have garbage collection.  We can't guess what your form is doing, what it loads while opening or whether it cleans up stuff properly. depending on the number of objects on the form that's a problem in the form's code, not Access. Without that code we can't help.

since update 2405. that doesn't mean there's a bug in Access, it means you only noticed the problem recently. Or a problem in those forms finally reached the crashing point. The version number doesn't explain anything anyway. Access is a desktop product, not used in programming. Problems like the one you described are almost always caused by hacks like forms that open forms that open forms. Or multiple levels of nester reports. Or Excel sheets that lookup in other sheets, that lookup in other sheets.

I hope it is a bug in 2405, but I am looking for a way to get this verified.
I discovered this in our application, and have tested it by creating a new empty database. I removed all code behind the form. so basically it is just only a form with some controlls on it.
I have tested it with several controlls, the more controlls you put on it the earlier the slowness appears. it even appears with a form with only a textbox for example, but then you need more loops.

I'm almost certain it's a bug in the form. Without the form's code we can't help. This isn't a programming question as it is - there's no relevant code. In any case, you won't find verification in a programming Q&A site. Very few developers use Access and those that do typically use it for storage in one of their applications. In 99.99% of cases it's end users that create and use Access Forms for their UI, in ways that developers wouldn't use

For this loop, you'd certainly need to throw in a bunch of DoEvents to accurately approximate usage. Access can't actually process the relevant events associated with opening and closing forms without a DoEvents call until after your function terminates.

Just wondering what are the reasons for close votes

@PanagiotisKanavos: I'm usually a big fan of your comments and answers, but, in this case, you are wrong. :-) There is a sizable MS Access developer community, there are a lot of large (legacy) line-of-business applications written in VBA, and if the same code worked last month and does strange things the next month, a broken Office update is the most likely cause (don't ask me why I know this sigh).

In the meantime I found a lot of questions in Microsoft Q&A complaining about delays like this. I really thought things like this stopped 10 years ago when they stopped trying to push everyone to SharePoint and Access Services but .... then I remembered that MS really wants people to move to Azure.

PS: And yeah, I haven't work with workgroup databases since 2001

This is bug in the latest Access v 2405, I'm having the same issue on our application.
We have multiple databases and different files on multiple locations.
So the version on their pc gets replaced by a fresh one daily.
The users have different databases and .accde version files.
and have worked like this for years.
Something changed in 2405 because the users on a controlled Microsoft Update environment are not affected.(2402)
The users that report this issue the most are opening and closing forms more than others. so like the comments said it probably has something to do with the VBA garbage collection or lack of.
I've reported it to Microsoft but on the last message they gave me a :
"Access does not fall under my scope and you do not have premier support.
So what I would recommend is to roll back (as you did), as the rollback seems to have a positive impact on the issue, and wait until the NEXT Office 365 update.
If the issue still persists after the next update, roll back again and look into purchasing support that does include Access.

You may try to write a comment for one of their news in Access Blog, https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/access-blog/bg-p/AccessBlog. I don't see a topic for 2405 but you may try to ask in 2404 for example. These are the public comments and you can get better results. If there will be a silence or "not our scope" then it will be public reject of client issues. This worked for me twice - they were broken DAO accessibility and when I wrote a comment about it in the corresponding article, I was receiving corresponding confirmation - yes, we have such an issue.

Confirmed here:
https://www.accessforever.org/post/performance-issues-and-crashes-when-loading-forms-in-version-2405
and apparently it is in the progress of being fixed.

The bugfix from Microsoft will be delivered for Current Channel with Version 2406, Build 17726.20126.  This release is now gradually rolling out during the week starting June 26.  If you are on Current Channel, but do not yet see this build version, you should be able to use "Update Options - Update Now" from the Account screen to force the update now.


And finally, the move from Current Channel to Monthly Enterprise Channel has paid off for once.
